# Create a $http.get properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, http-get

I would like to create a $http.get service properly but I have trouble with services in AngularJS. I create this code and It works but all the code is in the controler :

```
var monApp = angular.module('monApp', []);
monApp .controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://port:serveur/fichier.xml').then(function(response) {
            var x2jObj = X2J.parseXml(response.data); //X2J.parseXml(xmlDocument, '/');
            var tableauJSON = X2J.getJson(x2jObj);
        }, function(a, b, c) {
            alert("Impossible de télécharger le fichier");
        });
    }
]);
```

Can you help me to create it in service ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you read about [how to create services?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect solution, the controler :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "userService",
    function($scope, userService) {
        userService.getData();
    }
]);
```

The web service :

```
 app.service("userService",["$http",
        function($http) {
            _this = this;
            this.getData = function() {
                $http.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "accept, origin, authorization"};
                $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + window.btoa('username' + ':' + 'password');
                $http.get('http://YourServer:YourPort/rest/api/2/auditing/record').
                success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

create a service with name `fichierService` and a function `getData` like

```
monApp.factory("fichierService", function($http) {
  return {
    getData: function() {
         return $http.get('http://port:serveur/fichier.xml');       
    }
  }
});
```

and use that `fichierService` service in your `PhoneListCtrl` controller by inject

```
monApp .controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','fichierService',
function($scope, $http, fichierService) {
    fichierService.getData().then(function(response) {
        // rest of code
    }, function(a, b, c) {
        alert("Impossible de télécharger le fichier");
    });
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
monApp.service('myFooService', function() {
    this.get = function (url) {
        return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                  var x2jObj = X2J.parseXml(response.data); 
                  var tableauJSON = X2J.getJson(x2jObj);
               });
    }
});
```

and then you can use your service like this

```
monApp.controller('fooCtrl', function($scope, myFooService) {
    myFooService.get('http://foo.com/foo.xml');
});
```

This should give an idea on how to start implementing your own service.

Comment: is monApp.fooService correct ? should be  monApp.service